# Is it possible to buy a combined train ticket to Heathrow that takes the railair?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, airport-transfer, lhr

I would like to buy a train ticket from Swindon to Heathrow, changing at Reading to take the [railair bus](http://www.railair.com/).  However the online train ticket services, such as [GWR](http://gwr.com) do not offer me these tickets suggesting that I go via London or Hayes and Harlington.  I can buy the train ticket and the railair ticket separately from different websites but I am worried that there is a reason I am not being sold the combined tickets.

Is it in fact possible to buy such a combined ticket?

Comment: The rail websites do not show every allowable rail fare that can be sold. So be a little bit skeptical of the price it gives you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, and it can even be done on the [GWR ticket website](http://tickets.gwr.com/)! You need to search for a ticket from Swindon to *Heathrow Bus*, and it'll give you them as shown here:

[image: GWR site]

The ticket will be valid to Heathrow Terminal 5 as well, if that's where you wanted to go